# Modelling changes in a distribution over time

Tags: r, time-series, distributions, bayesian

`ggridges` does a nice job of visualizing the change in a distribution over time.

```
df <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bdetweiler/bdetweiler.github.io/master/data/sample.csv')
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = age, y = year, group = year)) + 
    geom_density_ridges()
```

[image: ggridges]

Clearly the data is becoming less concentrated at 80, and expanding to people in the 50s-70s range.

How would I go about modelling this change over time? Since I am dealing with ages, my data is discrete. I could run a time series for each age, but it seems like I would miss out on the overall trend.

I would be particularly interested in any Bayesian methods that might accomplish this.

Comment: Did you ever find an approach that worked for you?

Comment: @user2602640 I ended up plotting the median age over time as well as the skewness and kurtosis of the age distribution. http://bdetweiler.github.io/projects/grad-project/c-diff-brian-detweiler.pdf

Comment: Thank you! So looks like you went for a qualitative, visual representation of the data, without modeling? (also, remind me to not get C. diff, geez)

Comment: Yes, a bit of a simplification but I think it got the point across. And yes, do your best to avoid hospitals :)