# Has a distribution changed over time (by category)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, categorical-data, time-varying-covariate

I have information on percentage spending on 5 household categories (food, clothing, shelter, entertainment, education & sport, other) for all families in a county in 2005. I have the same percentages for 2015. I don't have individual level data, only the percentages. How can I test to see if the relative distribution has changed over time?
I looked at this question: [Modelling changes in a distribution over time](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/328060/modelling-changes-in-a-distribution-over-time) which provides the distribution, but it is continuous (not 5 categories). Further I dont need to visualize it (since I can do that with a side by side bar chart) but a statistical test.
I was also suggested the chi square test; case 1 of this document:
https://www3.nd.edu/~rwilliam/stats1/x51.pdf
However a senior colleague pointed out that I was not allocating a binary response like people into categories, so "counts" here are dollars and not people, so I cant use chi square.
So what test do I use here? ANOVA?