# How to track changes in a distribution over time?

Tags: time-series, data-visualization

If I have a distribution like:-

[image]

is there any simple way to describe it, other than mean/mode and standard deviation?  It's a histogram of the output of a device, and is totally random in actual data but this kinda shape.  I want to be able to track any significant changes to it over time.  Is the only solution just to store all the column values every time and flick through the consecutive histograms?

[Best way to track 'significant changes' in large time based data sets](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/297930/74762) and [Modelling changes in a distribution over time](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/328060/74762) came up, but those are either much broader or dead ends (so far).

Comment: It depends on what you might already know/understand about how this behaves, and kind of information you want to get out of it. One possibility might be to try to model it as a mixture (is there a reason it looks like two separate but overlapping groups there?) and then see how the parameters of that mixture changes; it may be easier conceptually to deal with a few more-or-less interpretable parameters than the entire distribution.

Comment: @Glen_b It's 3 identifiable interleaved normal distributions, but how they mix is unknown. Red, green and blue pixel values. So track the parts rather than the whole? 3 means and 3 std. devs?  Hmmm...

Comment: 1. The information you just revealed would be important to include in the question. 2. Not just three means and 3 sd's but also 3 proportions that sum to 1. Total of eight free parameters

Comment: You could look at [tag:control-chart]s